# What kind of hornet is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, hymenoptera

I live in France, in western suburbs of Paris. For a few days I have seen two of the insects below in my apartment. It is slightly smaller than a thumb, say 4cm (1.58") (sorry for not putting a ruler next to it but I was afraid it could chomp out my hand).

[image]

I tried to use this picture to differentiate the hornet:

[image]

(from left to right: bee, wasp, European hornet, Asian hornet).

It looks like this is the [European hornet](https://wildlifeinfrance.com/insects-france/hornet-in-france) and I did not kill it (apparently they are useful, not sure about that) but would like to be ready with the flamethrower next time if needed. We are also actively encouraged to report [Asian hornets](https://wildlifeinfrance.com/insects-france/asian-hornet-in-france).

Comment: You've identified it correctly; the size/markings/coloring are right for the European hornet worker female. They should not be in your house, though; I'd be concerned that there's a nest in the building and some of the hornets are confused as to how to get outdoors. If you can open the window for them, it might work, but move slowly. I really hate killing things, but if they were stuck in my house (and this used to happen with some regularity at one of my dwellings) I would use a rag or whatever was necessary to protect my humans from a confused hornet trying unsucessfully to get outside.